# What is the towers' damage?

Tags: hexdefense

In [HexDefense](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gotow.hexdefense), what is the actual damage each tower type (and its upgrades) do? Having this information will be helpful for maximizing the damage output of my layout.

I care less about the actual numerical damage values (because I don't know the creeps' health so it's meaningless anyway) and more about comparing the various towers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some reverse-engineering, I managed to find the stats from the Android 2.2.3 version of the game:

```
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
|    Tower    | Damage  | # Projectiles | APS  |   DPS   |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
| Minigun 1   |   10.00 |             1 | 3.13 |   31.25 |
| Minigun 2   |   11.00 |             2 | 2.84 |   62.50 |
| Minigun 3   |   18.00 |             3 | 2.58 |  139.46 |
| Minigun 4   |   30.00 |             3 | 2.35 |  211.31 |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
| Laser 1     |   22.00 |             1 | 1.25 |   27.50 |
| Laser 2     |   88.00 |             1 | 1.06 |   93.12 |
| Laser 3     |  352.00 |             1 | 0.92 |  322.94 |
| Laser 4     | 1408.00 |             1 | 0.81 | 1140.08 |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
| Rocket 1    |  150.00 |             1 | 0.40 |   60.00 |
| Rocket 2    |  200.00 |             2 | 0.47 |  188.24 |
| Rocket 3    |  290.00 |             2 | 0.55 |  321.11 |
| Rocket 4    |  440.00 |             3 | 0.65 |  859.76 |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
| Shockwave 1 |   53.33 |             1 | 1.00 |   53.33 |
| Shockwave 2 |  140.27 |             1 | 1.00 |  140.27 |
| Shockwave 3 |  368.90 |             1 | 1.00 |  368.90 |
| Shockwave 4 |  970.21 |             1 | 1.00 |  970.21 |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------+---------+
```

- ## Projectiles - meaning, the number of projectiles shot per attack.

  - Although it doesn't look that way, the higher-level Minigun tower actually shoots multiple times per "attack".
- APS - Attacks Per Second.

  - Apparently the Minigun and Laser towers do shoot slower after upgrading (though this is hard to spot on the Minigun because it shoots more projectiles per attack).
  - The Shockwave tower works a little differently (it's a true damage-over-time mechanism). It's best to refer solely to its DPS stat and ignore the damage/projectiles/APS stats.
- DPS - Damage Per Second.

Since the Laser and Shockwave towers have the highest damage *and* can damage multiple creeps at once, they seem to be the best towers to get in the late-game (along with Lightning towers, of course).

Comment: Did you find any info on attack range?  How about Lightning tower stats?

Comment: @deft_code I can also extract these stats, but I was mainly interested in damage - changed my title accordingly. If you're really curious you can open new question(s) about these and I'll try my best to answer them when I have the time to dig into the code again :)

Comment: Would you still add the Lightning tower damage here, instead of a separate question?

Comment: @deft_code you know, it would probably be best to just summarize all the information together. I'll delve into the code and update this answer with range and information about the lightning tower, but it might take me awhile before I get to it... I'll ping you when I do! :)